# Galois group of $x^6-5x^3+6$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $f = x^6-5x^3+6$.

I want to determine $\operatorname{Gal}(f/\mathbb{Q})$ without some group theory tricks (like Sylow's theorems) and without reduction $\bmod p$.

Let $L_f = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{3},e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}})$ be the splitting field. Then
$$|G = \operatorname{Gal}(f/\mathbb{Q})| = [L_f:\mathbb{Q}] = 18,$$
and $G\subset S_6$ and there is normal subgroup of index $2$.
Also $f = (x^3-3)(x^3-2)$ and therefore
$$G \triangleright  \operatorname{Gal}(x^3-2/\mathbb{Q}) = \operatorname{Gal}(x^3-3/\mathbb{Q}) = S_3$$
 But I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: That normal subgroup of index two permutes the zeros of $x^3-2$ and $x^3-3$ like $C_3\times C_3$. The zeros of both factors are acted upon cyclically. Add complex conjugation to the mix to get all 18 automorphisms.

Comment: In other words, the group looks like $$\langle a,b,c\mid a^3=b^3=1=c^2, ab=ba, cac=a^{-1}, cbc=b^{-1}\rangle$$

Comment: How to prove rigorously that subgroup acts as $C_3\times C_3$, it is obvious, but...